# I am facing while trying to create an object inside the class, How to resolve linking error?

Tags: c++, object, visual-c++

Sample code :

`ABC.h`

```
Class ABC{
    public:

    ABC();
    virtual bool a();
    virtual bool b();
    virtual bool c();

    protected: 
        ~ABC();

    private:

    BaseLM* m_lm;
    }
```

`abc.cpp`

```
ABC::ABC()
{
#ifndef KASH
    m_lm(new BaseLMD());
#else
    m_lm(new BaseLMI());
#endif 
}
```

I have `BaseLMD` and `BaseLMI` derived class from `BaseLM` and trying to creating an object inside `abc.cpp`
getting an error :

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

I wanted object to be created on the basis of the `# define ifndef KASH` inside `abc.cpp` class, please suggest the solution for the same.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By the way, where is the linking error?

Comment: Sorry , Its not a linking error, I am facing an error while compiling the code as : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: So, it is solved now?

Comment: @Dieter , No I tried corerect initializer list suggeted by Mike ,but still facing an error ,says error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from BaseLMD * to BaseLM*

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `BaseLMD` and `BaseLMI` classes?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
ABC::ABC()
:
#ifndef KASH
    m_lm(new BaseLMD())
#else
    m_lm(new BaseLMI())
#endif
{
}
```

Comment: @ Mike : I tried this , It says  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from BaseLMD * to  BaseLM*

Comment: @Gaurav Are you sure `BaseLMD` is derived class from `BaseLM` i.e. `BaseLMD` inherits `BaseLM`?

Comment: Yes , It is public inheritance from the BaseLM i.e BaseLMD publically inherits  BaseLM.

Comment: @Gaurav: That is impossible.

Comment: @Barry , But its the same As per my check .